# Expanding $\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}(1+a_m+b_m)$.

Tags: products

*Quite a complicated product in the form below occured in my research. I'm having trouble getting started in evaluating it.*

> Let $n\in\Bbb N\setminus \{1\}$, $(a_m)_{m\in\overline{1, n-1}}\in \Bbb R^{n-1}$, and $(b_m)_{m\in\overline{1, n-1}}\in \Bbb R^{n-1}$. Consider the product $$P:=\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}(1+a_m+b_m).$$ Expand $P$.

*Thoughts:*

I expect binomial coefficients to show up.

If we let $c_m:= a_m+b_m$, then $P$ becomes

$$\begin{align}
\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}(1+c_m)&= (1+c_1)\prod_{m=2}^{n-1}(1+c_m) \\
&=\prod_{m=2}^{n-1}(1+c_m)+c_1\prod_{m=2}^{n-1}(1+c_m),
\end{align}$$

which suggests that induction might work if I can guess what the expansion would look like.

I think I should be able to do this myself but I've been stuck for longer than I care to mention.

Please help :)

---

*NB*: Here $0\notin \Bbb N$.

Comment: What does the bar mean?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Here $\overline{1, n-1}=\{1, 2, 3, \dots, n-1\}$.

Comment: Btw why do you expect binomial coefficients? There are no terms that you can add up unfortunately...

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I don't know; inexperience, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}(1+c_m)&=(1+c_1)(1+c_2)\cdots(1+c_{n-1})\\&=1+\sum_{\text{cyc}}c_1+\sum_{\text{cyc}}c_1c_2+\cdots+\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}c_i\end{align}$$

Comment: What does $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}$$ mean? Also, what does one do, then, with the products over the $c_m$?

Comment: For example, $\sum_{\text{cyc}}c_1c_2$ takes all the possible pairs of the $c_i$s and adds them up. So we get $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}c_1c_2+c_1c_2+c_1c_3+\cdots+c_1c_{n-1}+c_2c_3+c_3c_4+\cdots+c_2c_{n-1}+\cdots+c_{n-2}c_{n-1}$$

Comment: For the $c_m$ write $$\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}(a_i+b_i)=\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}a_i\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{b_i}{a_i}\right)$$ and repeat the procedure!

Comment: What is $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}$$ called? I want to look up its properties so I can manipulate it.

Comment: Nevermind: it's the [cyclic sum](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Cyclic_sum).

Comment: :) ${}{}{}{}{}$